# How to move the pointer to the beginning?

Tags: c

I am using `malloc` and `realloc` to get string input from user, using `scanf`:
The code below is what I am using. I have managed to get all the user's input, but my pointer after the `realloc` is pointing to the end of the string. How can I make it point to the beginning?

```
int main() {
    char *ptr = NULL, input[2];
    ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Memory not allocated");
        exit(0);
    }

    scanf("%c", &input[0]);
    // printf("%s\n", input);
    *ptr = input[0];
    int counter = 1; 
    scanf("%c", &input[0]);
    // printf("%s\n", input); 

    while (input[0] != '\n') {
        counter++;
        ptr = realloc(ptr, counter * sizeof(char));
    
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            printf("Mermory not allocated");
            exit(0);
        }
    
        strncat(ptr, input,1);
        scanf("%c", &input[0]);
        // printf("%s\n", input);
    }

    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: you might want to check again. `realloc()` returns a pointe to the beginnig of the re-allocated memory

Comment: I'm pretty sure it returns a pointer to the beginning of the newly allocated memory which in my case will always be at the end as i am adding char by char into the memory block

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement a `getline` type of function. You should probably break this out into a separate function that takes a `char *` argument.

Comment: You are not appending your input to the previous input but always just copying 1 byte to the start of the memory. Therefore it might *look* as if it would point to the end. Also, neither `ptr` nor `input` hold strings as you never nul-terminate your input.

Comment: The argument to `realloc()` must be a pointer that previously was returned by `malloc` or `realloc`, and is still valid.  When it is successful, the function reallocates *the whole block*, copies (if necessary) the contents of the original block up to the size of the new block, and returns a pointer to **the beginning** of the new block.  It may happen that the start of the new block is at the same location that the start of the old block was, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: `strncpy(ptr, input, 1)` is copying to the beginning of the `ptr` buffer. Only `ptr[0]` is ever changed due to the third argument of the `strncpy` call being 1.

Comment: The user input is given to me, char by char. So everytime i get a char i make my memory block one char bigger and then use strncat to add it to the memory block

Comment: You mentioned `strncat` in your comment, but the code has `strncpy`.

Comment: Replace `strncpy(...` with `ptr[counter - 1] = input[0];`, anyway you don't need `strncpy` for copying a single character. You also need to null terminate your string: put `ptr[counter] = input[0];` right after the while loop.

Comment: Note also that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: Side note, not a very efficient idea to repeatedly calling `realloc()`. Maybe `malloc` with something big enough to begin with (say 50) and then `realloc` if needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating very simple task.

```
int main(void) 
{
    char *ptr = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    int ch;

    while((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    {
        char *tmp = realloc(ptr, (size + 2) * sizeof(*tmp));
        if(!tmp) {/* handle allocation error */}
        ptr = tmp;
        ptr[size++] = ch;
        ptr[size] = 0;
    }

    printf("You have entered %zu characters and the string is: `%s`\n", 
           size, ptr ? ptr : "(NULL)");
    free(ptr);
    return 0; 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/soEdM6ojc

Comment: Perhaps `char *ptr = calloc(1,1);` to handle the "first `ch == '\n'`" case.

Answer (score 2):

> but my pointer after the realloc is pointing to the end of the string.

No, it isn't.  Supposing that the size of the the block that `ptr` points to is initially less than or equal to `counter`, and that the `realloc(ptr, counter * sizeof(char))` call succeeds, the resulting value of `ptr` points to the same data that the original value of `ptr` pointed to, though its location in memory (the value of `ptr` itself) may be different.  Since `ptr` originally pointed to the beginning of the string, the result of the `realloc` also points to the beginning of the string or an identical copy of it.

> How can I make it point to the beginning?

It already does.